# Automatically sequence a formula throughout a column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to sequence the formula `=IF(NOT(ISBLANK($P3)),$P3+1,"")` down the Q column from Q3 onwards. Is it possible to do this without dragging and filling the column so I place the formula in to cell Q3 and it will auto fill in the function for the duration of the column?

Comment: You need `BYROW()` function.

Comment: Yes. Convert your cell range to TABLE and then it will be automatically updated if your insert new row.

Comment: The data is created by a function in a single cell. Can it be converted in to a table?

Comment: Hi @Harun24hr, trying to use BYROW using `=BYROW($P3:$P9999,LAMBDA(row,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(row)),row+1,"")))` and I get a spill error because there's no data past P8. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Why not extend your function in P3 to include the column?

Comment: Spill error means your formula working but it can't spill till end row of given range. You have data in resulting spill range. Clear data and you will get result.

Comment: Thanks @Harun24hr, must have been something I couldn't see. I cleared the whole column and re-added the formula and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Harun24hr for pointing me in the right direction with BYROW(). The formula to copy a formula for the duration of a column is :

`=BYROW($P3:$P9999,LAMBDA(row,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(row)),row+1,"")))`

Comment: You can accept your own answer to treat the thread as solved.

Comment: I can only do that tomorrow apparently but will do when I can :)